# jQuery add remove class onclick to a div

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, addclass, removeclass

I have created the code below, which successfully rotates an arrow, via the class rotate, on the first click.

But on the second click, i want the arrow to rotate back again. I have tried, using an else, and removing class on click. But this hasn't worked. Any suggestions, or help, would be great!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#first').click(function(event) {
          $(".content.firstArrow").addClass("rotate");
        }); 
        $('#second').click(function(event) {
          $(".content.secondArrow").addClass("rotate");
        }); 
        $('#third').click(function(event) {
          $(".content.thirdArrow").addClass("rotate");
        }); 
        $('#forth').click(function(event) {
          $(".content.forthArrow").addClass("rotate");
        });       
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(".content.firstArrow").toggleClass("rotate");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the code and leave one handler only:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#first, #second, #third, #forth').click(function(event) {
      $(".content." + $(this).attr('id') + "Arrow").toggleClass("rotate");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#first :not(.rotate)').click(function(event) {
  $(".content.firstArrow").addClass("rotate");
}); 

$('#first .rotate').click(function(event) {
  $(".content.firstArrow").removeClass("rotate");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use .toggleClass() Instead of addClass() or removeClass()